Is there a resource locking mechanism in k6
I have the need for assigning resources exclusive in k6 tests. For example I 50 credentials for the system under test which are not allowed to be used simultaneously. Is there any mechanism in k6 to achieve this? In my case these 50 credentials would be in on json array, so the resource to lock on the beginning of a test would be the index which would be released on the end of the test.
I'm aware that I can not test more concurrent load then I have of these resources, but I can live with that.
